# Angular 5 - TypeError: Object doesn't support this action on IE11- PolyFills support needed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, ecmascript-6, adminlte

Using AdminLTE dashboard + angular app for loading a login component which throws the following error in IE11 alone!

```
ERROR TypeError: Object doesn't support this action
at LayoutLoginComponent.prototype.ngOnInit
```

**Layoutcomponent.ts**

[image: Layout Component]

polyfills related to es-6 are loaded

```
/** IE9, IE10 and IE11 requires all of the following polyfills. **/
import 'core-js/es6/symbol';
import 'core-js/es6/object';
import 'core-js/es6/function';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-int';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-float';
import 'core-js/es6/number';
import 'core-js/es6/math';
import 'core-js/es6/string';
import 'core-js/es6/date';
import 'core-js/es6/array';
import 'core-js/es6/regexp';
import 'core-js/es6/map';
import 'core-js/es6/set';
import 'core-js/es7/array';
```

the loginTemplate which appears only after entering some text in the textfields
Does any other polyfills needs to be added for resolving this issue ?  [image]

Comment: Just to see if you actually are missing a polyfill, replace all of those lines with `import 'core-js';` to check

Comment: importing all modules from 'core-js' didnt work'